# Изменение размера шрифта в процентах

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так чтобы вместо того чтобы писать в @media screen, каждое изменение щрифта, размер шрифта сам менялся как в случае img, когда задаешь размер в процентах. Задал и текст в процентах но не вышло

```css
p {
  font-size: 280%;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
```

Ответ нашел!

px – абсолютные пиксели, к которым привязаны и потому не нужны mm, cm, pt и pc. Используется для максимально конкретного и точного задания размеров.

em – задаёт размер относительно шрифта родителя, можно относительно конкретных символов: "x"(ex) и "0"(ch), используется там, где нужно упростить масштабирование компоненты.

rem – задаёт размер относительно шрифта , используется для удобства глобального масштабирования: элементы которые планируется масштабировать, задаются в rem, а JS меняет шрифт у .

% – относительно такого же свойства родителя (как правило, но не всегда), используется для ширин, высот и так далее, без него никуда, но надо знать, относительно чего он считает проценты.
vw, vh, vmin, vmax – относительно размера экрана.

vw – 1% ширины окна

vh – 1% высоты окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант использовать единицу измерения REM.
И тогда размер вашего текста будет зависть от размера шрифта html элемента.
И вы сможете ограничиваться изменение 1 свойства в медиа запросах, а остальной шрифт будет масштабироваться автоматически.

[Документация по свойствам](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units)

Comment: rem – задаёт размер относительно шрифта <html>, используется для удобства глобального масштабирования: элементы которые планируется масштабировать, задаются в rem, а JS меняет шрифт у <html>.

vw, vh, vmin, vmax – относительно размера экрана